# How to get the images src which are in template field of gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Picture" ItemStyle-Height = "150" ItemStyle-Width = "170">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="150" Width="150"
           ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("PicturePath", GetUrl("{0}")) %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate> 
    <ControlStyle Height="150" Width="150" />
    <ItemStyle Height="150" Width="150"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I know how to get images src by using getElementById.But my requirement is to get image src from gridview template field.I just want to display all the images src which are in grid into list box.src should be like **src="http://localhost:61027/Images/JellyFish.jpg"**

Comment: Include what you are trying to achieve so that we can point you in the right direction.  There are many ways to get the src.

Comment: i just want to store all the src of images present in grid.  src should be in form src="http://localhost:61027/Images/JellyFish.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the underlaying data item in the GridView **RowDataBound** Event.
If your Listbox id is lbImageSource, for example, then here is the code you'll want:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
lbImageSource.Items.Add(String.Format("src=""{0}""", drv("PicturePath").ToString()))
End If
```

You'll probably want to clear the listbox at some point as well. The GridView **DataBinding** event should work for that.

```
lbImageSource.Items.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 (pass the variable to the front end):

- When the server is binding, add all the src to an object and render it as a hidden div so the front end can have it

Method 2 (grab it with jQuery):

- $('#<%= YourGrid.ClientID %> img');
- That will get you all the img items so you can iterate through them to get the src

Comment: I am a new bie to asp.net. I have no idea about jquery.can you please post some sample code,so that i can try something.